# SEO / Perfomance domain matters

Tags: seo, domains, performance

If I register a domain by some domain registrar and than host in on some hosting provider, does the SEO or performance matter?

E.g. I register the domain in UK and then host in Dallas, are there any performance issues and does it have impact to SEO? I guess not but I would like to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problems. As long as you use a quality registrar and a quality host. Select companies with good reputations. This is not where you want to save a buck since the cheaper options are often tolerant of bad behavior and do not care about reputation. The last thing you want is to be associated with a bad registrar and a bad host. Neighborhood does effect SEO.

Comment: No sweat. Good luck with your site!